# Adding a class to a certain element in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new working with ReactJS, I started a project a simple CRUD just for practice. So, I have a table and I want to add a class so that this element disappears when I press a button

The problem is when I press the button delete, React adds a class to all  elements, disappearing all of them

How to delete only the parent element of a clicked button ?
I tried to get the id of an event but I don't know how to specify to what element I want to add a class.

```
deleteTask(e, id){
  //let trDelete = 
  e.currentTarget.parentNode.getAttribute('key');
  M.toast({html: 'Task Deleted'})
  const currState = this.state.active;
  this.setState({active: !currState});

    }
```

```
{
this.state.tasks.map(task => {
    return (
        <tr data-key={task._id} key={task._id}  className={this.state.active ? "scale-transition scale-out": ""}>
            <td>{task.title}</td> 
            <td>{task.description}</td>
            <td>
                <button className="btn light-blue darken-4" onClick={(e) => this.deleteTask(e, task._id)}>
                    <i className="material-icons">
                        delete
                    </i>
                </button>
                <button className="btn light-blue darken-4" style={{margin: '4px'}}>
                <i className="material-icons">
                        edit
                    </i>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    )
  })
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply CSS classes on a per-item basis, you will need to track the class(es) of each item by adding extra component state.

A simple solution here would be to update your `deleteTask()` function:

```
deleteTask = (event, taskId) => { 

    this.setState(state => {

        /* 
        Iterate each task in state, and add isDeleted to task(s) with matching id 
        */
        return { 
            tasks : state.tasks.map(task => 
            (taskId === task._id ? { ...task, isDeleted : true } : { ...task }))
        };

    }, () => {

        /*
        Show toast popup after stat change
        */
        M.toast({html: 'Task Deleted'});
    });
}
```

And then update your table rendering to account for the new `isDeleted` item state:

```
<tr data-key={task._id} key={task._id}  
    className={ task.isDeleted ? "scale-transition scale-out": ""}>
    { /* Existing table markup */ }
</tr>
```

Comment: Nice, but I get this warning when I delete an element `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.`

Comment: You're welcome, interesting - what else is happening in your `deleteTask()` function? Are any items in the tasks array being duplicated?

Comment: @JORGE just updated answer based on your updates - does this help?

Comment: I have problems using triple dot operator in my project, there an alternative way to use it ?

Comment: Sorry to come back to you so late - glad I could help 

Answer (score 0):

The class is being added to all of them, because you're iterating over each item and assigning the class to each task item based on `active` being constant.

If you want to delete or hide a task, the `setState` should be affecting `this.state.tasks` and not `this.state.active`.

I'm guessing your update and state is intended to look more like this:

```
deleteTask(e, id) {

  // Return new task objects to prevent mutation of state
  const tasks = this.state.tasks.map(task => {
    return task.id === id ? {...task, active: !task.active} : {...task};
  });

  // Executes callback after state update is complete
  this.setState({tasks}, () => M.toast({html: 'Task Deleted'}));
}
```

Disclaimer: I don't know what you're using to transpile, so you might have to use the equivalent of the object spread and property shorthand.